# Creating Multiple .ipynb Notebooks in Google Colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

is it possible to create more than **the one default notebook** in Google Colab Pro?

I first tried to create a new file with the .ipynb file extension and it shows up like this:
[image: create new file]

Then I tried to create a new notebook like this:
[image: create new notebook]

And that file opens up the same way as just creating an new file:
[image]

Basically, I'd like to create multiple notebooks like creating an new .ipynb notebook in Jupyter notebooks so I can use Google Colab the same way as Jupyter notebooks. Is this possible in Google Colab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Colaboratory is quite different from jupyter notebook, you can't create and use 2 notebooks in a single session as it would also hurt the resources of the google colab. They do not have made this feature. So it is not possible yet.